# Equivalent JPA query for MYSQL Query

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

am still learning JPA framework. I have created my mysql query below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tia.VoucherId) As Voucher, f.Name As Farm, CONCAT(far.FirstName, ' ', far.LastName) AS Farmer, s.Name Season, fa.Name As FarmingActivity
FROM Enrollment e INNER JOIN TemporaryInputsAllocated tia ON e.Farm_Id = tia.Farm_Id
INNER JOIN Farm f ON e.Farm_Id = f.Id
INNER JOIN Farmer far ON f.Farmer_Id = far.Id
INNER JOIN Season s ON tia.Season_Id = s.Id
INNER JOIN FarmingActivity fa on e.FarmingActivity_Id = fa.Id;
```

what is the equivalent JPA query?

Comment: Do you have foreign keys which is in the inner join?

Comment: @ahmetkamaran yes

Comment: did you map your tables into entities with relations?

Comment: @ahmetkamaran Yes i did

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have foreign keys, you don't need to inner join clauses. You can change your query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(tia.VoucherId) As Voucher, e.Farm_Id.Name As Farm, CONCAT(e.Farm_Id.Farmer_Id.FirstName, ' ', e.Farm_Id.Farmer_Id.LastName) AS Farmer, tia.Season_Id.Name Season, e.FarmingActivity_Id.Name As FarmingActivity FROM Enrollment e, TemporaryInputsAllocated tia where e.Farm_Id = tia.Farm_Id
```

This query returns an object list.